# Navigating to folders not visible in Files

Tags: command-line, filesystem

In files I know I can go in the search and put in a path to navigate to it, but I'm trying to access a folder not normally visible `/.m2/` from my home directory, I can do it from terminal but it wont let me do it from the "files" application.
I can do `/Downloads/` to go to downloads but cant do it for `.m2`, what should I do?
Also, is there a way to take my path from the `terminal` and open the folder it is navigated to?

Comment: to answer your second question: do you mean like thunar .m2/ where thunar is your file-manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File or directory names starting with `.` correspond to *hidden* items in Unix.
Most applications that deal with files can be configured to either show them (or account for them in some other way, e.g., autocomplete, etc.) or not by default.

In the case of nautilus, 
click on the icon with three horizontal lines, next to the top right, and check the box "Show Hidden Files".

Answer (score 1):

Files or folders where the file name starts with a dot as in `.m2` are treated as "hidden files" in linux. That means that they are considered files or folders that the user does not need to see during his day to day work.

You can see and search for hidden files and folders by turning on "Show hidden files" in Nautilus. You can find the option under the button with the three vertical dots in the top bar. A faster way to toggle this option on and off is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.

If you feel that that folder `.m2` should not be hidden, then rename it so it does not have a dot at the beginning of the file name.